# pytest-xdist - running parametrized fixtures for parametrized tests once without blocking

Tags: python, testing, pytest, pytest-xdist

Consider the following example (which is a simple template of my real issue, of course):

```py
import time

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
def heavy_computation(request):
    print(f"heavy_computation - param is {request.param}")
    time.sleep(10)
    return request.param


@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
def test_heavy_computation(param, heavy_computation):
    print(f"running {param} with {heavy_computation}")
```

We have parametrized tests (with 5 parameters) dependent on parameterized fixtures (with 5 different parameters), giving a total of 25 tests.
As you can guess by its name, the fixture does some heavy computation that takes a while.

##### TL;DR - how can I use pytest-xdist such that each worker will run one `heavy_computation` and its dependent tests right afterward (without separating this file into 5 files)?

Now the full details:

In order to speed up the testing process, I'm using [pytest-xdist](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist). A known issue of pytest-xdist, is that it does not support running fixtures once, which means, for example, that if we have 5 workers that will grab tests 1-A, 1-B, ..., 1-E (to be clear: x-y is a combination the fixture and test parameters), **all** 5 workers will run the heavy computation, which yields the same result - we don't want that.

In the official docs of the package, there's a [proposed solution](https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to.html#making-session-scoped-fixtures-execute-only-once) that suggests using a file lock. The problem with this approach, as far as I understand, is that all tests waiting for a fixture to be ready will hang until the process that started first will finish, instead of waiting inside that process, leaving the other workers to start computing the rest of the fixtures.

**My goal** is to gather a fixture and its dependent tests to run as a group inside a single worker, without blocking other workers. Is there an **elegant*** way to do this?

- yes, of course, one solution is separating this file into 5 files with hard-coded fixtures - I don't want to do that if there's a nicer solution.

Hope that it all makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I managed to find a solution - in case someone needs this sometime in the future, here's what I came up with:

1. Change the code to something like this:

```py
import time

import pytest


class BaseTest:
    PARAM = None

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def heavy_computation(self):
        print(f"heavy_computation - param is {self.PARAM}")
        time.sleep(10)
        return self.PARAM

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param", ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
    def test_heavy_computation(self, param, heavy_computation):
        print(f"running {param} with {heavy_computation}")


for i in range(1, 6):
    class_name = f"Test{i}"
    globals()[class_name] = type(class_name, (BaseTest,), {"PARAM": i})
```

2. Run pytest with the flag `--dist loadscope`

##### Explanation

The new code creates multiple tests class **dynamically**. This replaces the parametrization of the fixture in the original code. Eventually, we end up with 5 different test classes, each having 1 fixture (with the relevant parameter) and 5 dependent tests. By adding the `--dist loadscope` all tests of a class are sent to the same worker, and therefore the relevant fixture runs there only once.

**Note:** pytest ignores the base class (meaning, it doesn't run its fixture and tests) because its name doesn't start with "Test" - in contrast with the newly created classes, that do have this prefix.